# Is there a taxonomy based on concepts of "fiscal" and "utility" data?

Tags: metadata

Is there are a theory, division, classification or taxonomy schema for open data? With classes like "fiscal" and "utility".

### Explaining and illustrating

Perhaps **"utility"**  (or "public utility" or day by day util data) is not the correct term... I will try to explain: *public utility open data* are the input for innovation and improving the quality, of [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_sector) and [public services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_service). Some examples show better the concept:

- [Postcodes](http://index.okfn.org/dataset/postcodes/): all people need, all the time we need the same database... So, it is util for us.  The *open data* is the list of all postcodes of a country.
- [Data Packaged Core Datasets](https://github.com/datasets): each dataset (of this project) is a set of util data.
- [Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word): all people need...  The *open data* is the [list of all words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary), or any other more complex structure like a dictionary.
- [Digital street lines](http://www.openstreetmap.org): OSM has a *repo* with "very util data" (!).

**"Fiscal data"** perhaps, also, is not the correct term (perhaps **audit** is a better name), but some examples show the concept:

- [Data of the IUCN Red List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUCN_Red_List)
- [Data of spending reports (ex. UK)](http://data.gov.uk/data/openspending-report/index)
- [Data of the Corruption Perceptions Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption_Perceptions_Index)
- [Data from Wikileaks](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2011/jan/31/wikileaks-data-journalism)

Of course, a dataset can be both, "util" and "fiscal", so in a classification schema they are like "root [facets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_classification)".

---

### notes

Historically [OpenData activism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activism) started as *"**fiscal**"* (with activists working in [data scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) for *audit* the data)... Today Open Data community also is investing in [cleansing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing), organize and standardize ***util** data*, for open collective/collaborative use.

Comment: wand taxonomy is utility but its proprietary :(

Comment: @albert, "Wand taxonomy" is a good clue ;-)  Another clue, a friend showed an illustration with a kind of "open government hierarchy of needs", grouping the pyramidal layers in _A_ and _B_, with *A=Services+Process+Data*, and *B=Collaboration+Participation+Transparency*... So,  _A_ is the "utility" (internal) part, and _B_ is the "fiscal" (external) part. Need adaptations: this question is not about only-gov-data, but also data that can be used directally by all community members.

Comment: Another clue for "util data". France is debating the concept of “public interest data” — datasets held by the private sector whose publication would serve the public interest... See [etalab.gouv.fr questionary](https://www.etalab.gouv.fr/en/gouvernement-ouvert/questionnaire-donnees-dinteret-general)